# ESP8266 и Clion

Tags: c++, arduino, clion, esp8266

Есть плата на базе esp8266 и соответственно прошивка к ней, написанная на плюсах и файл .ino для Arduino IDE. В идеале, прошивка должна собираться в .bin файл в Arduino IDE  и заливаться на плату через нее. Я бы хотел вместо этого работать в CLion (переубедить не пытайтесь, дело вкуса). Про ардуино плагин я знаю, но он не поддерживает мою плату (NodeMCU). Что посоветуете?

Comment: написать автору плагина, написать плагин самому, выбрать другой инструмент, выбрать другую плату ну и ещё десяток вариантов.

Comment: посмотри тут.................... https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2020/08/arduino-from-hobby-to-prof-p1/

Comment: Статья хорошая, но не решает мою проблему полностью